# ASP.NET Core Identity two phase login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am a ISV working on upgrading the software.  The system is a client/server solution that has two levels of authentication.  I am wondering how best to implement this in ASP.Net Core 5.

The two phases work fine right now in the old webserver (not C#):

Level 1: Authentication & Authorization the number of clients connecting to the server.  I won't get into the details on this, but the client software sends the correct info so the server knows one "client" from another, it then keeps count of all the connections and stops new connections once the license has been reached.  All this is done IN MEMORY.  There is no reason to and actually presences an opportunity to hack the system if this information is saved to a DB.  There is role-based security in this situation, there are public-facing clients, employee-facing clients, and admin-facing clients.

Level 2: Authentication & Authorization users on a given client.  Based on the rule of the client will dictate the type of user logging in, public or employee.

Right now the client software does the Level 1 login and the human does the Level 2.  The systems are totally independent of one another.  I am wondering if there is some way to correctly use ASP.NET Core Identity to implement both levels of Authentication & Authorization where level 1 is ONLY in memory and level 2 is stored in the DB.  How would it be done?

Comment: This is not really what ASP.net Core Identity is designed to do. You could potentially implement some custom sign-in logic but there isn't a good way to check how many people are logged in to the application simultaneously.

Comment: I hear ya, do you other suggestions?  P.S. I’m not counting people/users, rather client instances.

Comment: It seems that you need to use the in-memory database such as redis so that you can save the count into it for your counting feature.